# Why does a string type array doesn't take data when you overwrite the already stored values in the elements with input from keyboard?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to store values like "01" and "10" into an array but the int array would take "01" as "1". Hence I decided to use string array.While declaring the string array, I initialized it with

```
string array[n] = {0};
```

On compiling the code it shows an error saying :

```
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_M_constructnull not valid"
```

While just changing the type of the array to integer, it works fine.

I tried to not initialize the

```
string array[n]={0};
```

The code then works fine!

Can we conclude that the string type array cannot overwrite the values already stored in the elements?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string arr[n] = {0};
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
    cout<<arr[i];

    }  
 }
```

this is the output of the code:

```
1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_M_constructnull not valid
```

Comment: `string arr[n] = {0};` -- This is not legal C++.   Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile time constant, not a runtime value.  Assign just to a `string` (not an array) the value `0` and ask again.

Comment: No you can't conclude that. Newbies know very little about C++ (obviously) so don't try and reason about it too much, you're probably starting from false assumptions.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/2311167)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems with

```
string arr[n] = {0};
```

First, `n` is not a compile time constant so that makes `arr` a VLA (Variable Length Array).  Those are not standard and are only supported as an extension by some compilers.  You can use `-pedantic` compiler flag to stop if from compiling.

Secondly the `= {0}` part is going to initialize the first string in the array with the integer `0`.  Since `0` is also the null pointer value it gets treated as a pointer and the compiler tries to construct a string from a null pointer.  This is undefined behavior and in this case `std::string` throws an exception.

To fix all of this use a `std::vector` (which can have a run time size) and let it default construct all of the elements for you.  You can do that like

```
std::vector<std::string> arr(n);
```